# Wpml cookie want to block in my rest api response

Tags: cookies, mobile, crash, wpml

I have an issue with my mobile application crashing due to a cookie coming in my rest api response from wpml plugin wordpress.

The scenario is as follows:-

- I try to login using rest API ( it's using jwt-auth for authentication)
- the return response header has a set-cookie *wp-wpml_current_admin_language_{hash}*
- the app is using reactnative and it tries to write the cookie and crashes the application.

Solution needed

- we need to remove this cookie from the response header

Comment: _I try to login using rest API_ - where are you logging in to and what for? wp-admin or something else?

Comment: I tried to login via mobile app (it is user login) using rest API.